# edit commit comments in sourcetree after pressing commit

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I added only 1 comment in the commit change. I didn't push yet. How can i add more comments to it? I'm a bit afraid to do things wrong.

[image: sourcetree]

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Just want to give more clarity to this old question with these simple pictures, although this is for the latest commit only (updated for SourceTree 2.5.2).

1. Under 'Workspace', select 'File Status':

[image: File Status]

2. Click the commit message box to expand it, then you will find 'Amend last commit' by clicking 'Commit options' at the bottom right:

[image: Commit Message and Amend Last Commit]

Comment: Pictures for the win :D

Comment: Hehe Thanks, I found it easier with pictures

Comment: There is no "Working Copy" in new SourceTree (mac, 2.2.4). Now you need to select WORKSPACE > File status (or just press ⌘1), the "Commit options…" will be there. Note: you may need to click "Commit message" field to expand it and show "Commit options…"

Answer (score 7):

You can do this before pushing. There is a checkbox at the bottom left of the Commit dialog which says "Amend latest commit", when you check it the previous message will appear in the box and you can edit it, then hit Commit to modify it.